# What is the allowed Max Length for a Rich Text Field on Sitecore 7.2?

Tags: sitecore-client, richtext-editor, fieldtype

I was asked to implement a new page, Privacy Policy page, I decided to use Sitecore rather than create a whole new outside application.

Thus, I picked a similar page that content editors were using for textual content. At first I copied and pasted into the RTE but I could not press "accept" or even "reject", so I truncated said document and found that I reached threshold.

Furthermore, I also tried to type the content into the RTE, this time I was able to get more content to load, but I hit the threshold again.

I did some digging in the settings, not config files, to see if there is some setting on RTE, but I could not find anything.

Did anyone have a similar experience?

Comment: Did you get chance to have a look at this question asked on Stack Overflow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536922/sitecore-rich-text-field-max-length

Comment: yes, i did look at that, but I believe that is for validation, where if you exceeded that threshold, you would receive some sort of error message. anyhow, I researched this and I can't find anything that would help me resolve this. Thanks for your response

Comment: How long is the text you are entering? I tried with almost 300000+ characters without hitting any threshold. Also check if you have any restrictions on allowed characters in RTE fields ?

Comment: Agreed with Amitabh, I have tried with more then 11,00,000 characters and not facing any issue... There must be some validation restriction applied to environment/field. I have checked in Sitecore 8.2 update-6 and Sitecore 9 Update-1 with default as well as full rich text editor. And both is working fine for me.

Comment: Check the `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="???">` value in your web.config and make sure it has not been set to a low number

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look on any of `SharedFields / UnversionedFields / VersionedFields` tables in master or web database, you will see that datatype of `Value` field is `nvarchar(max)`. This datatype is used to store value of any field not just rich text but single line text and so on.

Based on MS SQL Server documentation the max size for a column of type NVARCHAR(MAX) is 2 GByte of storage.
Since NVARCHAR uses 2 bytes per character, that's approx. 1 billion characters.

Mind `HTML tags` that are stored in rich text field also so maximum number of characters is less than above mentioned.

---

e.g.

```
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
```

10 characters of `Contact Us` text will be stored in 19 characters long value in db as you have HTML tags before `<h2>` and after `</h2>` so almost double the size of original text.

---

**The maximum number of characters in rich text is therefore approx. 1 billion characters but the effective maximum number of characters depends on how many customizations to text you have and what is the ratio of "pure" text stored in that field.**