# In sitecore RTE, copy from word, is empty when size is huge

Tags: sitecore-client

`Copy from Word` option in Sitecore *Rich Text Editor* **cannot save** when the *size of word is huge*, is there any `Word size limit` and is there way to *increase the size*?

please let me know your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: This could be an indication of poor architecture with your content. Data sources should be small chunks of text not complete pages.

Comment: Did you read this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10683/what-is-the-allowed-max-length-for-a-rich-text-field-on-sitecore-7-2

Comment: @Dean OBrien Yeah I read, there is nothing concrete in that article